# Angularjs Java Rest Service 415 Unsupported Media Type

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, rest

Im working with java spring mvc and angular js.

I created a rest service:

```
@RestController 
public class UserApiController { 

@Autowired
private UserService userService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/createUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody void addUser(@RequestBody UserRequestDTO newUser) {
    userService.addUser(newUser);
}
```

And my angular controller like this:

```
var newUser = { surname : "orozco", name: "daniel", password: "pepe", email:"dani@dani.com" };
$http.post(getCompletePath("users/createUser"), JSON.stringify(newUser))
    .success(function () {
         alert("ok");
    }).error(function () {    
    });
```

My UserRequestDTO

```
public class UserRequestDTO {

private String email;

private String password;

private String name;

private String surname;
```

+getters and setters

It return the following error: 415 (Unsupported Media Type).

If I send a string o no parameters, it works. So, the problem is in the parameters

Comment: show your `UserRequestDTO` code

Comment: done. I added the UserRequestDto code

Comment: can you make sure `jackson` is installed among your WEB-INF/lib libraries (or pulled in among maven libraries)? your dto is correct, and angularjs `$http` should default already to `application/json` when posting, so that's correct as well.

Comment: Your are right, i forget org.codehaus.jackson. Thanks very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forget to include org.codehaus.jackson in pom.xml. It fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't know AngularJS but try to add Content-Type in your AngularJS code. It should look something like this (according the spec https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) :

```
    var newUser = {
     surname : "orozco",
     name: "daniel",
     password: "pepe",
     email:"dani@dani.com" };
    var req = {
     method: 'POST',
     url: getCompletePath("users/createUser"),
     headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
     data: newUser};
    $http(req)
     .success(function () {alert("ok");})
     .error(function () {});
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of the Content-Type header, try to include it explicitly
as follows,

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: getCompletePath("users/createUser"),
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 },
 data: {surname : "orozco", name: "daniel", password: "pepe", email:"dani@dani.com" },
}

$http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```